# Remove url from string using PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone please tell me how to remove url from a string using PHP

I have this string

```
src="http://cdn1.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/34918177/layering__1_.0_standard_90.0.png"
```

Desired Output:

```
src="/uploads/chorus_image/image/34918177/layering__1_.0_standard_90.0.png"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) buil-in php function for this.

For example:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://cdn1.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/34918177/layering__1_.0_standard_90.0.png';

$parsed_url = parse_url($url);

var_dump($parsed_url);

?>
```

Output:

[image]

So, after the url is parsed, the bit you want is found on `$parsed_url['path']`. Hope this helps.

Comment: `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)` basically.